# Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I am really new using Spring
I am developing a simple JEE application with JSF+Hibernate+Spring
I am facing some problems when trying to update values on a DAO
I'm sure the problem is related with the Spring configuration xml file, but I can't find out what is.

This is my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javarevolutions"/>           

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/revolutions?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="username" value="netbeans"/>
        <property name="password" value="netbeans"/>
    </bean> 


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>    

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>/com/javarevolutions/jhs/persistence/Login.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>/com/javarevolutions/jhs/persistence/Alumnos.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>/com/javarevolutions/jhs/persistence/Articulos.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>                

    <!--DAOS-->
    <bean id="loginDAO" class="com.javarevolutions.jdbc.dao.ImplLogin">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="alumnoDAO" class="com.javarevolutions.jdbc.dao.ImplAlumno">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>        
    </bean>        

    <!--BOS-->
    <bean id="loginBO" class="com.javarevolutions.jhs.bo.LoginImplBO">
        <property name="loginDAO" ref="loginDAO"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="alumnoBO" class="com.javarevolutions.jhs.bo.AlumnoImplBO">
        <property name="alumnoDAO" ref="alumnoDAO"></property>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

This is the DAO declaration

/

```
*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.javarevolutions.jdbc.dao;

import com.javarevolutions.jhs.persistence.Alumnos;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

/**
 *
 * @author Mol
 */
public class ImplAlumno extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IfaceAlumno{

    @Override
    public void insert(Alumnos obj) {
        //getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(org.hibernate.FlushMode.AUTO);
        getHibernateTemplate().save(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Alumnos obj) {
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Alumnos obj) {
        getHibernateTemplate().merge(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Alumnos> getAll() {
        List<Object> lista=getHibernateTemplate().find("from Alumnos");
        return (List<Alumnos>)(Object)lista;
    }

}
```

This is the error LOG

```
Información:   Hibernate: select alumnos0_.matricula as matricul1_0_, alumnos0_.usuario as usuario2_0_, alumnos0_.nombre as nombre3_0_, alumnos0_.app as app4_0_, alumnos0_.apm as apm5_0_, alumnos0_.edad as edad6_0_, alumnos0_.sexo as sexo7_0_, alumnos0_.fecha_registro as fecha_re8_0_ from revolutions.alumnos alumnos0_
Advertencia:   #{alumnoBean.insert}: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
javax.faces.FacesException: #{alumnoBean.insert}: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.checkWriteOperationAllowed(HibernateTemplate.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:617)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:340)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:308)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:617)
    at com.javarevolutions.jdbc.dao.ImplAlumno.insert(ImplAlumno.java:21)
    at com.javarevolutions.jhs.bo.AlumnoImplBO.insert(AlumnoImplBO.java:41)
    at com.javarevolutions.jsf.bean.BeanAlumno.insert(BeanAlumno.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 41 more

FATAL:   JSF1073: se ha interceptado javax.faces.FacesException durante el procesamiento de INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Mensaje=#{alumnoBean.insert}: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
FATAL:   #{alumnoBean.insert}: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
javax.faces.FacesException: #{alumnoBean.insert}: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{alumnoBean.insert}: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.checkWriteOperationAllowed(HibernateTemplate.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:617)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:340)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:308)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:617)
    at com.javarevolutions.jdbc.dao.ImplAlumno.insert(ImplAlumno.java:21)
    at com.javarevolutions.jhs.bo.AlumnoImplBO.insert(AlumnoImplBO.java:41)
    at com.javarevolutions.jsf.bean.BeanAlumno.insert(BeanAlumno.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should add a transaction manager bean.

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> 
</bean>
```

**and**

Add the `@Transactional` annotation for the methods that should be a transaction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have canged the configuration as you said, but I have another problem now... Posted above

Comment: One qualifier I would add is setting readOnly to false. `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` and to make sure you're importing the correct annotation, `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`, not `javax.transaction.Transactional`. Hoping that saves somebody some time.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this:

```
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

With:

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
```

Answer (score 2):

Once changed the xml configutation file and the DAO
I get the following error:

```
Grave:   Exception while loading the app
Grave:   Undeployment failed for context /JSFHibernateSpring
Grave:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'alumnoBO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy273 implementing com.javarevolutions.jdbc.dao.IfaceAlumno,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'com.javarevolutions.jdbc.dao.ImplAlumno' for property 'alumnoDAO'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy273 implementing com.javarevolutions.jdbc.dao.IfaceAlumno,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.javarevolutions.jdbc.dao.ImplAlumno] for property 'alumnoDAO': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

XLM configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javarevolutions"/> 

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> 
    </bean>                              

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/revolutions?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="username" value="netbeans"/>
        <property name="password" value="netbeans"/>
    </bean> 


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>    

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>/com/javarevolutions/jhs/persistence/Login.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>/com/javarevolutions/jhs/persistence/Alumnos.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>/com/javarevolutions/jhs/persistence/Articulos.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>                

    <!--DAOS-->
    <bean id="loginDAO" class="com.javarevolutions.jdbc.dao.ImplLogin">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="alumnoDAO" class="com.javarevolutions.jdbc.dao.ImplAlumno">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>        
    </bean>            

    <!--BOS-->
    <bean id="loginBO" class="com.javarevolutions.jhs.bo.LoginImplBO">
        <property name="loginDAO" ref="loginDAO"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="alumnoBO" class="com.javarevolutions.jhs.bo.AlumnoImplBO">
        <property name="alumnoDAO" ref="alumnoDAO"></property>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

DAO

```
package com.javarevolutions.jdbc.dao;

import com.javarevolutions.jhs.persistence.Alumnos;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Isolation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 *
 * @author Mol
 */
@Transactional
public class ImplAlumno extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IfaceAlumno{

    @Override     
    public void insert(Alumnos obj) {
        //getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(org.hibernate.FlushMode.AUTO);
        getHibernateTemplate().save(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Alumnos obj) {
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Alumnos obj) {
        getHibernateTemplate().merge(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Alumnos> getAll() {
        List<Object> lista=getHibernateTemplate().find("from Alumnos");
        return (List<Alumnos>)(Object)lista;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the problem in the following ways:

1. Check all the mandatory data is provided of Bean/Model class at saving time.
2. Check the concept of unique constraints is following or not, if not add different data in a unique column.
3. If the problem is still not resolved then add @Transaction annotation above the method but to use @Transaction method create an Object of HibernateTransactionManager

```
@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
           HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
           txManager.setSessionFactory(getLocalSessionFactoryBean().getObject());

return txManager;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java configuration , simply add @EnableTransactionManagement (org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement)